# Use private GPT model with company data

Tags: chatgpt-api

I want to set up a private ChatGPT that can access company Data such as E-Mails or even Oracle Databases.

So if I ask a prompt when the last email by customer XYZ was received it can search the Mails for the specific mail.
Or it can access the Oracle database and tell me Infos about specific tables.

Is that possible somehow and where do I have to start?

All I found so far were some repos that use Langchain but those just seem to work on single files and is not exactly what I am looking for